# Using SSL/TLS is slowing down the performance of Java based client server application

Tags: performance, ssl, tls1.2

I am working on a trading application where we get streaming rates from the server within seconds or even milliseconds. The server and database run on the same Linux environment. The client is actually accessible from any location using JNLP/ Java web start. The user can directly download the JNLP file from a provided URL and launch the client application on his system and directly connect to the server regardless of where the server is located.

Now, the problem is when we are not using SSL, the application runs just fine. But with SSL slowness is observed which drastically reduces the performance of client application. However, the same thing is not observed when client and server both are running on the same machine (Windows). Does anyone have an idea about possible reasons which can cause this slowness?

Comment: There are too much unknowns on how this application works, how much slow down you see and where do you see it. But in general the encryption itself does not slow down access much. But the TLS handshake in general does and doubly so if no sessions are reused. Also, large certificate chains might badly interact with TCP flow control which can cause additional problems. All of this will affect the application if it rapidly creates new TCP/TLS connections (instead of using HTTP keep alive over a few established connections) and it has more impact on WAN and LAN than on localhost.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich. Thanks for the reply. The TLS handshake (3 way handshake) happens just one time between client and server using sockets. Once the connection is created between both applications, it's only the read and write operations that are happening very frequently because of streaming rates.